# How to color C++11's new keywords `final` and `override` in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, c++11, ide, syntax-highlighting, keyword

I'm using eclipse CDT to develop C++11 projects. I can configure eclipse as I like, except that I cannot make eclipse recognize C++11's new keywords: `final` and `override`.

Is it possible to color `final` and `override` in current eclipse?

Comment: in before "they are not keywords"

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***Others*** parameter on the ***Syntax Coloring*** tab.