# How to make Eclipse recognize the __far modifier?

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, softune

I received a big embedded codebase that I have to get comfortable with. I started using Eclipse for C/C++ Developers (Oxygen release 4.7.0) a couple days ago.

I am getting the following types of false error (the code compiles with the prehistoric compiler Softune Workbench):

[image: Eclipse thinks *__far* is a type]

This line of code intends to define a pointer named `wRecData` of type `__far result_data_headerW`. As far as I know `__far` keyword is used to access the external ram here. Although Eclipse can't resolve `__far` (this is why it is underlined red) it still thinks it is a type and `result_data_headerW` is the name of a local variable and the rest of the line is garbage.

How could I make Eclipse recognize that `__far` is part of the type and not the type itself?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398910/how-to-color-c11s-new-keywords-final-and-override-in-eclipse. Other than that though I guess Eclipse would need a related lexer and parser

Comment: It is possible to do this, but a lot of work: http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/How-to-add-Keyword-to-CDT-Parser-td166002.html

Comment: @Toby Sorry but what does this have to do with syntax _coloring_? I think this is an issue of syntax _recognizing_.

Comment: My bad, ignore the first link!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having Eclipse recognize `__far` it's probably easier to ignore it.

The [Adding Include paths and symbols in Managed Build System](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm) section of the documentation documents how to define symbols. If you define `__far` with an empty value, Eclipse should ignore it.